# Finding the integral of the function involving box function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

This is the question
[image]

I thought that I would find the points of discontinuity(which would be the points where the box function has an integer within it) and would integrate as shown below

[image]

Where f(x) is the given function. But I realized that this would be cumbersome.

Can someone explain to me the solution given in the book

Or

Provide with a different solution

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint the property used is $f (a+b-x)=f (x)$ now note that $x^2$ is even function so it remains unchanged. Then in greatest integer function it becomes $5+(-5)-x =-x $ thus this integration changes. Then they have used the fact that integer function for begative numbers is $-1$ of tge given integer eg $-2.13$ is $-3$ so thus they have followed the steps and got $I=-I $ so $2I=0$ thus $I=0$